# Is there a standard way to denote a matrix with a single column (or single row) deleted?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I would like to list the rows of sub matrix $M(i|j)$, which is the sub matrix of $M$ where the $i$-th row and $j$-th column have been deleted. So I have said that $M'$ is the matrix $M$ with the $j$-th column deleted, and $M'_k$ is the $k$-th column of $M'$, so that $$M(i|j) = \begin{bmatrix} M'_1 \\ \vdots \\ \widehat{M'}_i \\ \vdots \\ M'_n \end{bmatrix},$$
where $\widehat{M'}_i$ indicates that the row $M'_i$ should not be included in $M(i|j)$.

I am not too satisfied with my invented $M'$ notation. I am looking at [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Submatrix/Notation) which provides several standard ways of denoting submatrices. But none seems convenient for writing a matrix where only a single column (or row) has been deleted. Is there a standard (or at least common) way to denote such a thing?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. At least, the textbooks I've read which have treated something which uses submatrices have different notations. For example, one considers a matrix as an object, and notes a submatrix by a subscript. On the other hand, another considers a matrix as a vector arrangement, so just writes the arrangement without the relevant vector.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085240/notation-for-removal-of-row-column-from-matrix

Comment: How about $M_{-*k}$ to remove the $k$-th column?